# build project then facing this issue

Tags: build

AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit. Error output:
aapt2.exe W 03-19 18:24:42 10200 10820 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'.

Build project then facing this issue try many answers but not work anyone please help any have answer this error